# Create a div for background image

Tags: html, css

How can i create a css class and after that call in a div?

I have this:

`<div class="row2" style="background-image: url(http://new38.devsck.ro/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/footer-img-1.jpg); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;">`

But, when i try to create a class .background ()not work at all. Can you help me with that?

Comment: The DIV is in class `row2` so you would add CSS to it by using `.row2 { }`. Alternatively you could just add the `background` class to the DIV like this: `<div class="row2 background" ... >`

Comment: Can you give me an example, please? It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

### First option

You have added your DIV as follows:

```
<div class="row2" ... >
```

Now to add CSS to the DIV, you could either add CSS to the `row2` class:

```css
.row2 {
  /* put your styling here */
}
```

---

### Second option

Another option would be to add the DIV to the `background` class:

```
<div class="row2 background" ... >
```

And then add your CSS like this:

```css
.background {
  /* put your styling here */
}
```

Comment: .background need to be in .row2 or separate in css?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to add the DIV to a class called `background`. Then you can just implement the second option. `.background` does not need to _be in_ `.row2`. Here is an example of how to use the [CSS .class Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp). If this doesn't answer your question, please update it and clarify your problem.